# Data content dont load on first page-load but does on 2nd page-load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem im been having is that the content in my view (the content that comes from database) aren't loading on the first page load. but it does on the second. Example

1. I go from my startpage to the view i have my content on (text and
   database method content)
2. First time i go there i only see my texts that are in the html.
3. I go to another page on my site
4. Then i go back to the previous view that have data content on. and now it shows that content.

Why isn't the data content showing on the first page load?, and how do I resolve this?

App/routing code:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/Employee', {
            templateUrl: 'Employee/EmployeeResult',
            controller: 'EmployeeController',
            controllerAs: 'EmployeeCtrl',
             })
```

Controller code :

```
angular.module('App')
    .controller('EmployeeController',
    function ($scope, $http, $location, getClassInfoForTeacher, $routeParams)
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.info;
        vm.info = getClassInfoForTeacher.get();

        vm.ClassClick = function () {
            $location.path('/Employee/EmployeeClassSelect');      
        }
    })
```

Factory code:

```
angular.module('App')
    .factory('getClassInfoForTeacher', function ($http) {
        var obj;
        $http.get("/employee/GetClassInfoForTeacher")
                .success(function (response) {
                    obj = JSON.parse('[' + response + ']');
                });
        return {
            get: function () {
                return obj;
            }
        };

    });
```

```html
<div class="emphome-wrapper" ng-controller="EmployeeController as EmployeeCtrl" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"  ng-repeat="g in EmployeeCtrl.info| unique : 'Grade'">
            <h1 >Årskurs {{g.Grade}} </h1>
            <div class="col-md-4 gradeSelect" ng-repeat="c in EmployeeCtrl.info | filter:{Grade: g.Grade}" ng-click="EmployeeCtrl.ClassClick(c.Id)"> {{c.Name}}</div> 

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This is what i get back from the function now.

Controller code:

```html
angular.module('App')
    .controller('EmployeeController',
    ['$scope','$http','$location','$routeParams','getClassInfoForTeacher',
    function ($scope,$http, $location,$routeParams, getClassInfoForTeacher)
    {
        var vm = this;
        
       getClassInfoForTeacher.get().then(function (response)
       {
          
            vm.info = response;
           
            console.log(vm.info);
         });
      
        vm.ClassClick = function () {
            $location.path('/Employee/EmployeeClassSelect');
        }
    }])
.filter('unique', function () {
    return function (collection, keyname) {
        var output = [],
            keys = [];

        angular.forEach(collection, function (item) {
            var key = item[keyname];
            if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                keys.push(key);
                output.push(item);
            }
        });

        return output;
    };
});
```

factory code:

```html
angular.module('App')
    .factory('getClassInfoForTeacher', function ($http) {
        
        var teacherService = {}

        teacherService.get = function ()
        {
            return $http.get("/employee/GetClassInfoForTeacher")
                .success(function (response) {
                    response = JSON.parse('[' + response + ']');
                                                    
                });      
        };
        return teacherService;     
    });
```

html code :

```html
<div class="emphome-wrapper" ng-controller="EmployeeController as EmployeeCtrl" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"  ng-repeat="g in EmployeeCtrl.info| unique : 'Grade'">
           
            <h1 >Årskurs {{g}}</h1>
            <div class="col-md-4 gradeSelect" ng-repeat="c in EmployeeCtrl.info | filter:{Grade: g.Grade}" ng-click="EmployeeCtrl.ClassClick(c.Id)"> {{c.Name}}</div> 

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

and this is what it shows on the screen  when i just have {{g}}in html

```html
Årskurs ["{\"Id\":\"AA6C05F9-98DF-4A8D-B055-10DB07557F0D\",\"Name\":\"1C\",\"Grade\":1,\"TeacherId\":\"1E51E989-8ED5-4988-B929-4FBCD8A7977D\"}","{\"Id\":\"C07D54D9-01B0-4CC8-A8CC-0FDD47EAFE5C\",\"Name\":\"1B\",\"Grade\":1,\"TeacherId\":\"1E51E989-8ED5-4988-B929-4FBCD8A7977D\"}","{\"Id\":\"15218673-874B-41C1-9910-AD4F185F5730\",\"Name\":\"2C\",\"Grade\":2,\"TeacherId\":\"1E51E989-8ED5-4988-B929-4FBCD8A7977D\"}","{\"Id\":\"4711EEEE-4B56-4FD8-9A15-648CE00090A3\",\"Name\":\"2A\",\"Grade\":2,\"TeacherId\":\"1E51E989-8ED5-4988-B929-4FBCD8A7977D\"}"]
```

Ive tried with {{g.Grade}} but then it shows nothing on the view. How can i just put the grade of each object in the view in this array. If the array contains more than 1 grade "1" it should only display that once. And not 2 times. how do i do this?

well i kind found a solution to this. but . it feels like this arent the correct way to do it.

i removed the parse in factory so i just returned the promise.

and then i changed controller like this. 
 and it worked with {{g.Grade}} in the html

```html
getClassInfoForTeacher.get().then(function (response) {

        vm.info = JSON.parse('[' + response.data+ ']');
        console.log(vm.info);
    });
```

is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Any errors on first load of the page?

Comment: No errors on any page-load

Comment: Link to your markup/html

Comment: `$http.get` is asynchronous. At the point at which you call `getClassInfoForTeacher.get()` and it returns the local variable `obj`, it's `undefined`

Comment: I recommend putting some `$log`s to find out when exactly things are happening. Put one before the `$http.get()` and one inside. Print timestamps in both and see how long this data access request takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're falling into the typical AJAX issue since it's asynchronous.

```
angular.module('App').factory('getClassInfoForTeacher', function ($http) {

    // Also it's much more readable to create factories using an object
    var teacherService = {};  

    teacherService.get = function () {
        return $http.get( /* your code */ );
        // ^^ return the entire PROMISE
    };

    return teacherService;
});
```

Your controller: (Note use `['$scope', function ($scope) { }]);` notation for when you minify your code.

```
angular.module('App').controller('EmployeeController', 
    ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'getClassInfoForTeacher',         
    function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, getClassInfoForTeacher /* put angular things FIRST */)
{
    var vm = this;

    // Then gets hit after the AJAX has completed and will populate your model
    getClassInfoForTeacher.get().then(function (response) {
        vm.info = response;
    });

}]);
```

Comment: ok. i did as u described but now it dosnt show anything . do i need to change my hmtl code aswell for it to work with the new code? . added the html code...

Comment: do a console log on that response there, see what's coming back

Comment: if i put console log outside that function info is undefined. and if i do inside its ... as edited code shows.  but it seems the array in info only lives inside that scope so it dosnt permantly apply it so therefor i cant get anything out on the screen

Comment: You need to parse it then, looks like you got the JSON you wanted! Should be all set now :)

Comment: yes, after some thinking with ur feedback. it was able to resolve the problem. thx =)

Comment: Accept the answer and such if it helped! Glad you got it working, best of luck